# Update a variable in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to update a multiplicative value to a variable.

I know that I can do += and -= for addition and subtraction and *= for multiplication, but I don't fully grasp the entirety of that type of operation.  Can someone point me to the documentation that covers this?  I can't seem to find it on python.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well technically you are never updating python variables (integers, strings and floats among many other are immutable), you are re-assigning a value to a name.

`+` is shorthand for `add()`, `*` is shorthand for `mul()` and `-` is short for `sub()`.

since you are re-assigning variable, you are essentially performing these operations (when adding, substracting, multiplying, dividing or whatever it is that you do):

```
 a = 1
 a = a + 1     # a = 2
 a = a * 2     # a = 4
 a = a - 1     # a = 3
```

`+=`, `-=` and `*=` are just shorts for the above expressions.

i.e. the above can be restated as:

```
 a = 1
 a += 1
 a *= 2
 a -= 1
```

python docs for operators: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html
see also python docs for inplace operators for more information: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#inplace-operators

Comment: Unary operators are irrelevant here. You're looking for the [in-place operators](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#inplace-operators).

Comment: Note that where `x = []`, that `x += [0]` is not the same as `x = x + [0]`

Comment: @glibdud thanks, fixed.